# Inverse Laplace Transform Failing: $\frac{1}{\exp (\beta \tau )-a}$

Tags: integral-transforms

I have tried various approaches to get the solution to this inverse transform but all so far are failing.

```
tmpF[s_, b_, a_] := 1/(Exp[s b] - a)
InverseLaplaceTransform[tmpF[s, b, a], s, t]
```

which fails by just returning:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[tmpF[s, b, a], s, t]
```

I have tried

- Expressing as a series
- Simplifying as $\frac{1}{e^{-\beta}-1}$ which also fails

I am not sure if there is anything else I can do. I have checked the analytic solution is correct (and does exist) in the post below on Mathematics SE and since with a few fellow postgrads.

- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869017/272850

Comment: I should also note that I have done a number of Inverse Laplace Transforms successfully but this is the only one that evades me!

Comment: looking at the discussion on the other site I'm not convinced this is such a well established solution that we should be surprised or bothered that mma doesn't find it.

Comment: The solution is well established though even if it returns a delta function form... I may perhaps resort to using 'Apart' although that has its own problems and will probably induce another question

Comment: You didn't explain what you wanted to do with `Root` exactly, but one thing I was curious about and I never knew the answer to is how to compute *all complex roots* of a polynomial numerically (and make sure we get them all).  There's a discussion of that here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/roots-of-polynomials-with-small-coefficients

Comment: Here's some more: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184107/finding-all-roots-of-polynomial-system-numerically  The answer doesn't discuss methods much, it just links to a library, but if this is the problem you wanted to solve then it's what you need (I'm curious about the algorithm)/

Comment: I moved the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38593771/4013571) so might be worth moving the comments onto that thread